# How can I save the data after modal is beign closed - angular

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

Hi have modal: in the modal I generating a data with $scope.text  from the js file by enter user and password from the user (he insert in input file 2 fileds in modal and I generate data from that- static link)

while I close the modal I loosing the data and if I will open again the modal from that link the data will disappear.  I would like to keep it , even until the browser is refreshed

Comment: What you have tried so far, Can you post that here?

Answer (score 1):

Bind the modal data to controller scope. after that you can use it.

see [plnkr example here](http://embed.plnkr.co/As959V/)